# postgresql restore database using dumpall file

Tags: postgresql

I'm planning to use the below commands as mentioned in this command to dump and restore my database -

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html

```
To dump all databases:

$ pg_dumpall > db.out
To reload database(s) from this file, you can use:

$ psql -f db.out postgres
```

When I use dump all its going to dump all the database, why do I need to specify during my restore command...

```
ie; psql -f db.out postgres
```

What does postgres signifies here?

Comment: `What does XXX signify here?` <--what is the question?

Comment: I added <postgres>(within angular brackets) and not sure why it was not visible..edited it now..

Comment: I see. The point is: you must be connected to *some* database. (and database `postgres` will be needed anyway to administer the initial `create database` commands, anyway) Here `postgres` is the name of the *(meta)* database to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ psql --help
psql is the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Usage:
  psql [OPTION]... [DBNAME [USERNAME]]

General options:
  -c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME      database name to connect to (default: "tramfjord")
  -f, --file=FILENAME      execute commands from file, then exit
```

In `psql -f /my/file postgres`, postgres is the `DBNAME`, or database name.  Your username will probably default to postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple command:

```
remove *-h localhost*
```

if you don`t have host

```
su postgres    
psql -h localhost dump_database_name < /tmp/dump_all.sql
```